# create ERC20 token with custom parameters in transfer function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have created the ERC20 token and its working fine, using the following code

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x299d8c3672b95f5a38af9a8d69590c4546219859#code

Problem
i want to add one custom parameter while transfering erc20 token so i have added one parameter project Type in the transfer function as mentioned below

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x869Ac98EC03f220F6C49AaD2AabA4ad53924e74B#code

whenever i tried to transfer some token from metamask or from the application using web3. transaction is getting failed. Is anybody faced the same issue?

Regards
Manikandan C

Answer (score 3):

The ERC20 interface is not a piece of code. It is an agreement amongst programmers on what the contract should look like.

Agreement between groups of programmers is usually called a "standard". That's why ERC20 is often called a token standard.

In code, the standard is implemented as an interface so the compiler can check weather you have complied to the standard.

If you **change** the interface, you change the standard. Therefore what you have programmed is no longer an ERC20 token. It is therefore not surprising that other software refuse to accept the smart contract as an ERC20 token because it is not an ERC20 token.

### If you want to make modifications

It should be noted that interfaces only enforce what **MUST** be implemented. There is no restriction on any functions you want to add. So you are free to add a `specialTransfer()` function if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. then can i go for ERC223 token?https://github.com/Dexaran/ERC223-token-standard   Because In erc223 token transfer function,  have data parameter to store the other information

Comment: Ah, that's cool. I didn't know Solidity supports function overloading. If ERC223 is really backwards compatible with ERC20 then yes, wallets will treat it as ERC20

Comment: Yes ERC223 supports backward compatibility. However the problem is erc223 is just a proposal not a standard token. So I'm not sure whether it's safe to use.